# parsing application/atom+xml in html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url, feed

we know that all blog show his blog 's rss feed by

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyBlog RSS Feed" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MyBlog" />
```

but are you know any regex to get feedurl from this

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyBlog RSS Feed" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MyBlog" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an XPath query like this one:

```
//link[@type='application/rss+xml']/@href
```

It'll pull out any RSS feed URL for you. **Never parse XML or HTML with regular expressions, ever.** [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) is specifically designed to query XML and HTML easy for you. It's available in nearly every technology stack, [including .NET](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3383961/NET-and-XML-XPath-Queries.htm).

XML is not regular, and so [regex is the incorrect tool to parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: what if the html is not valid xml?